# Error in in visual studio 2010 professional installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i try to install visual studio 2010 professional but i am getting error and it is log file.

```
>
[09/27/11,21:21:50] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft Application Error Reporting. MSI returned error code 2
[09/27/11,21:21:51] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Designtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:21:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:51] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft Application Error Reporting. MSI returned error code 2
[09/27/11,21:23:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:52] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:53] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Designtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/27/11,21:23:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
```

[IMG]http://i52.tinypic.com/11hcn0o.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Development tool questions are on-topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you installing over the network?  There's at least some indication that you can solve this by copying the ISO locally, or that the ISO you are using is corrupted and needs to be re-downloaded..

Comment: no dear have copied that setup at my local machiene. itried 2 setups but both are giving same error.